# AVPlayerLayer frame doesn't fit into UIView for video player

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerlayer

I'm trying to display a video with this code:

```
self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: videoUrl as URL)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: self.videoPlayer)
self.videoPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
playerLayer.frame =  self.videoPlayerView.layer.bounds
self.videoPlayer.play()
```

but it does not appear inside of the UIView (i.e. self.videoPlayerView). It just shows a thin Rect at the middle of the screen as shown in the screenshot. How do I fix this?
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO7bg.png)

Answer (score 1):

try this...
set the layer's frame to equal the view's frame

```
self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: videoUrl as URL)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: self.videoPlayer)
self.videoPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
playerLayer.frame =  self.videoPlayerView.frame
self.videoPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the code is in Swift not Obective-C, I would change that tag! Secondly, how do you define the videoPlayerView frame? Thirdly, you change the frame of the playerLayer after it has already been added. Thus the frame will not change visually! Set the frame before you add it as a subLayer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I did that but did not fix it

Comment: You changed where you set the playerLayer frame? If so my second point still stands, where and how do you set the videoPlayerViews frame?

Comment: In storyboard using autolayout

Comment: In what method are you making the calls?

Comment: Okay I found a way around it using an example provided in the Apple's Documentation for AVPlayerLayer [A convenient way of using AVPlayerLayer in iOS or tvOS is as the backing layer for a UIView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayerlayer?language=objc)